# Tenho a referência, mas quando rodo o CLR diz que falta a referência

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho esse include em meu projeto: `System.Web.MVC.Ajax`. Porem ao rodar a aplicação me aparece um erro de *runtime*, no arquivo `web.config`. Se eu comento a linha do erro no `web.config`, o erro aparece na linha de baixo, referente ao `System.web.MVC.Html`. Esse é o erro que aparece:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Erro de Compilação
>
> Descrição: Erro ao compilar um recurso necessário para atender esta
>   solicitação. Examine os detalhes específicos do erro e modifique o
>   código fonte apropriadamente.
>
> Mensagem de Erro do Compilador: CS0234: O nome do namespace ou o tipo
>   'Ajax' não existe no namespace 'System.Web.Mvc'. Precisa de uma
>   referência de assembly?
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Linha 22:          Linha 23:
>    Linha 24:         //aqui dá o erro. Linha 25:
>    Linha 26:
>
> Arquivo de Origem: c:\Projetos_MVC\Sistema.Mvc\Web.config    Linha: 24
>
> Mostrar Saída Detalhada do Compilador:
>
> Mostrar Origem de Compilação Completa:
>
> Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319;
>   Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34249

O que eu não entendo é que tenho a referência e veja os includes da minha controller e nenhum está com erros:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
```

Bem, esse é meu arquivo de rota, pode ser que seja útil:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BrandContext",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "BrandContext", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
        }
    }
```

E essa é minha view que eu estou começando a criar:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index - Teste de Partial View</h2>
```

Em ViewBag está dando o seguinte erro.

> ViewBag do not exist in the current context

Só não entendo o que realmente está acontecendo.

Abaixo meu package.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="4.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.5.6" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

O arquivo web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Como está seu `packages.config`?

Comment: Eu vejo como estão as instalações de cada pacote da sua aplicação MVC.

Comment: Já é a segunda vez que você me pergunta sobre ele. Tem a ver com referências também?

Comment: Sim, totalmente, mas as referências estão ok. Preciso agora do seu arquivo `web.config`.

Answer (score 1):

Está bastante errada sua configuração. Um aplicativo ASP.NET MVC possui dois arquivos `Web.config`, sendo um dentro do diretório `Views` e outro no diretório raiz. O que você fez foi misturar os dois.

Isto aqui precisa ser retirado:

```
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

Este trecho não pertence ao `<system.web>` do `web.config` raiz, e sim, à *tag* `<system.web.webPages.razor>` do `web.config` do diretório `Views`.

Uma configuração correta seria algo como:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Note que esta configuração é para o MVC5, e não para o MVC4, que deve ser seu caso. Faça as configurações com cuidado.

Comment: Cheguei agora do almoço e farei isso, mas eu não fiz nada que sugerisse uma mistura dos web.config. O próprio sistema fez isso creio, talvez ao criar minha view e algumas partial view, pode ser, mas eu não copiei nada ou posso ter feito quando inserir ou excluir algumas referências, mas isso é do dia-a-dia de todo programador.

Comment: Se faço isso, dá o seguinte erro: Descrição: HTTP 404. O recurso que você está procurando (ou uma de suas dependências) não pôde ser removido, seu nome foi alterado ou está temporariamente indisponível. Examine o URL e certifique-se de que está digitado corretamente. 

URL solicitada: /